# Check for similar values VBA Excel

Tags: vba, function, excel, similarity

I am developing this macro in Excel vba that will loop through a column of client names that are sorted from a to z and check to see which ones are similar and assign them the same client ID in the column adjacent to it.  I am using the `Like` operator to compare the names but for some reason it is not picking up on the similarities between the Names.  For example, I want it to think that Aetna and Aetna Medicaid are the same thing because they both contain Aetna.  I am not sure if this operator was meant to do this and if not, what would be the best way to go about this.  I have pasted the code below.  It is in the preliminary stages so for now it just outputs a `MsgBox` instead of assigning the client ID.  Also, the range is defined by a function which just sets it as a one column range.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Function SetInternalClientID()

Sheet9.Activate

Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Set rng2 = FindHeader("CLIENT NAME", Sheet9.Name)

Count = 0

For i = 73 To rng2.Rows.Count

ClientCheck = rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value Like rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value

If ClientCheck = True Then

MsgBox (rng2.Cells(i, 1) & " Like " & rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value)

Else

MsgBox (rng2.Cells(i, 1) & " NOT LIKE " & rng2.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value)

End If

Next i


End Function
```

Comment: You'll probably need to add wildcard characters. "Aetna*" matches "Aetna Medicaid". See [Like Operator (Visual Basic)(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Like` operator is often confused. It doesn't simply check if two strings match. Instead, the value to the left of the `Like` operator is the string to test against the pattern, which is to the right of the operator. 
`String_To_Test Like Pattern`

With that said, an expression such as:
`"Aetna Medical" Like "Aetna"` would return true, but `"Aetna" Like "Aetna Medical"` would return False.

Answer (score 0):

Porcupine is right. You will need to use wildcards like ? and * at either the beginning, end, or middle of your string. I would also consider using instr() to return a value if the two strings contain similar text.